# graphics.h for microsoft visual studio community 2017

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2017, bgi

I have been including the graphics.h in the header folder of vs project, but for some reason, it still says "No such file directory". I watched one of the videos and I saw that I need to get graphics.lib and I have no idea where the .lib file is since I searched everywhere for it. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you referring to console graphics APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the WinBGIm graphics library onto your machine (preferably to the desktop, where you can easily access it):

For Visual Studio 2005:     [BGI.zip](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/visual/BGI.zip)
For Visual Studio 2008:     [BGI2008.zip](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/visual/BGI2008.zip)
For Visual Studio 2010:     BGI2010.zip
ref:[http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/visual/)